# Meaning of "right by"

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "right by" mean in the following sentence?

> His company pulled up near the bridge, ***right by*** the White House.

Comment: I was surprised to find that "right by" doesn't seem to appear in online dictionaries. (Of course *right* and *by* do, by themselves, but the combination is a fair question given lack of resources.) I'd like to point out that the sentence seems to be missing a word; *pulled up* is likely what it should say. As it reads currently, the sentence doesn't make much sense.

Comment: yes, corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Right by" means "near" or "next to".

Comment: Most likely they used "right by" to avoid using _near_ twice in the same sentence.

Answer (score -1):

It means "SUPER CLOSE".

If you say it's "by" the white house, that means it's in the vicinity.

If you say it's "right by" the white house, you're stressing the closeness.

The distance the person is from the white house when he's describing it also is a factor.

If you say "right by" yet it's like a block away, you're probably miles from the white house when your describing it. If you were close to the white house when you said it that would mean it was mere feet away if not touching.